suspend mode actually uses lots of energy
I made a question some time ago was here , that said that ubuntu suspend mode uses alot of energy in comparison with windows 11, namely ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10
its not an opinion, its a fact since i tested many times, and in suspension mode ubuntu in just one nigth become without energy from 100% to 0% and so there is an issue with ubuntu.
And i migth add that with windows 11 with the same laptop go for days without need charging if i dont use that much the laptop.
you can ignore it or even close this question as the one i did but the issue will remain
and i must add that closing my previous question didnt make sense , since its not an opinion its a fact, you can check it either with a lenovo laptop equal to mine,Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5, or perhapes confirm with your own laptop. And see ubuntu uses in one nigth all the energy in suspend mode
the lenovo laptop in suspend mode goes from 100% to 0% in around 10h, as opposed with windows 11 consumes litle energy in suspend mode in the same time
And my questions remain the same, namely:
my question why is that true? why ubuntu 24.04 and 24.10 uses so much energy in comparision with windows 11 ?
And is expectable that ubuntu so will improve on this in the future?

Suspend mode uses a lot of energy for some people. On their hardware. Works properly on mine. Seems like a bug specific to that hardware or configuration. Has it been properly reported to the bug tracker? (AskUbuntu is not the bug tracker)

Where are you measuring current/power use and how?  Can you do a test where you unplug peripherals like USB devices and remove or disable wifi or bluetooth devices and see if it goes back to what you expect, as a troubleshooting measure?

The smooth road of software is likely found by using the same hardware as everyone else. But, if you hit a bump, unlike M$ where you might find the road simply ends, you can usually define a Linux problem and post where the community is actively developing that feature. Usually a bug report. But sometimes on repository sites like GITHUB or SOURCEFORGE. Also, consider other Linux avenues. Ubuntu may be bloated for your purposes. For example, a Linux base field lab monitoring computer may get by with a lighter Linux distribution.

i just use normally the computer, to plug to the internet i must use wifi is the only way.And my test was made using the computer full charged and was without battery maybe after 10 hours,unlike windows 11 that i can let it be on suspend and almost none energy was consume after the same 10 hours
